# #VALUE Error in Evaluate Function of Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find out what is wrong with the process below. In my sheet, there is a formula string which needs evaluation for different values of variable, *x*.

`(0.5*(23-9.81)*3*(x^2))*(x/3)+(0.5*9.81*(x^2))*(x/3)-1*((0.5*18.5*0.33*(2.5^2))*(x+2.5/3)+(18.5*0.33*2.5*x)*(x/2)+(0.5*(23-9.81)*0.33*(x^2))*(x/3)+(0.5*9.81*(x^2))*(x/3)+(100*0.33*(2.5+x))*((2.5+x)/2))`

I have a vba code which looks like this:

```
Public Function ev(r As Range, x As Double) As Variant
    ev = Application.Evaluate(Replace(r.Value, "x", x))
End Function
```

What's weird is that this function only works if the cell input is like

> =ev(Q25,10.01)

but not

> =ev(Q25,10.000000001)

or even

> =ev(Q25,10.00001)

Why is this happening? I need the program to calculate using small increments of up to `0.0000000001`. Thank you for your insights.

Comment: Note: the string above might be wrong but i am not sure why SO prints it like that. I am certain that there are no errors or missing parenthesis in the formula

Comment: Text that is enclosed in \* characters gets interpreted as italics. That's why your formula looked strange. If you escape the \* character like this: \\* then it won't create italics

Comment: Why don't you use `A1` instead of `x` in your formula and simply change the value in A1 ?

Comment: I edited the question and add code tags, so the formula displays as intended.

Comment: @teylyn, actually, the problem is in my other VBA code, where *evaluate* function is used. I just tried to use it in sheet so that I can check where the error is. My other functions include EVALUATE too, so it gives errors.

Comment: I think Evaluate can only handle a string up to 255 characters long.

Comment: @BigBen, yes sir. Checked to be lower than 255 chars. On a 149-char term, the program does not have problems solving. When on a 201-char term, the program gives the error.

Comment: for me `=ev(Q25,10.01)` also doesnt work or even `=ev(Q25,1)`

Comment: I think there's something wrong with `(0.5\*(23-9.81)\*3\*(x^2))\*(x/3)+(0.5\*9.81\*(x^2))\*(x/3)-1.5\*((0.5\*18.5\*0.33\*(2.5^2))\*(x+2.5/3)+(18.5\*0.33\*2.5\*x)\*(x/2)+(0.5\*(23-9.81)\*0.33\*(x^2))\*(x/3)+(0.5\*9.81\*(x^2))\*(x/3)+(120\*0.33)\*((2.5+x)/2))` I replaced `x` with `10.01` and directly entered `=(0.5\*(23-9.81)\*3\*(10.01^2))\*(10.01/3)+(0.5\*9.81\*(10.01^2))\*(10.01/3)-1.5\*((0.5\*18.5\*0.33\*(2.5^2))\*(10.01+2.5/3)+(18.5\*0.33\*2.5\*10.01)\*(10.01/2)+(0.5\*(23-9.81)\*0.33\*(10.01^2))\*(10.01/3)+(0.5\*9.81\*(10.01^2))\*(10.01/3)+(120\*0.33)\*((2.5+10.01)/2))` & it gave an error.

Comment: @SiddharthRout, I think that equation was edited to reflect a correct one. (0.5*(23-9.81)*3*(x^2))*(x/3)+(0.5*9.81*(x^2))*(x/3)-1*((0.5*18.5*0.33*(2.5^2))*(x+2.5/3)+(18.5*0.33*2.5*x)*(x/2)+(0.5*(23-9.81)*0.33*(x^2))*(x/3)+(0.5*9.81*(x^2))*(x/3)+(100*0.33*(2.5+x))*((2.5+x)/2))

Comment: Yes I checked the lengths of the strings. It is going beyond 256. And hence the error a correctly mentioned by @BigBen. You may also want to read up on https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-evaluate-method-255-character-limit.852781/

Comment: Sorry, I used *len* function in excel to check. there are only 201 characters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223575/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-jem-eripol).

Comment: @BigBen: Thats a valid answer. You may want to put it as one?

Comment: Please put this as an answer. I will accept this answer as it solved my confusion. Thank you :)

Comment: Also your equation can be wriiten as `(19.785*(x^2))*(x/3)+(4.905*(x^2))*(x/3)-1*(19.078125*(x+2.5/3)+(15.2625*x)*(x/2)+(2.17635*(x^2))*(x/3)+(4.905*(x^2))*(x/3)+(33*(2.5+x))*((2.5+x)/2))` Which is 149 characters

Answer (score 2):

There is a 255 character limit to a `String` passed to `Application.Evaluate`. You're running into that hard limit after `Replace`ing `x` with the corresponding numeric value.

Your options include:

- Breaking up the formula into pieces and `Evaluate`ing it in several steps.
- Rewriting the formula to something shorter as mentioned in the comments (though you may still surpass the 255 limit based on length of the proposed arguments).
- Using an approach like [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/236433/evaluating-formulas-greater-than-255-characters) and writing the revised formula to a cell, then reading back the calculated value.